# How to make dependent combo boxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this.
[image]

I need to get two dependent combo boxes.

- 1st combo - should have options toy 1 and toy 2
- 2nd combo - based on combo 1 selection No of wheels list should be shown
- 3rd combo - based on combo 1 selection Name should be shown

I tried the following code.
When form initializes, I get combo1 list
And when combo 1 selected, I load combo 2 and 3

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
   For i = 2 To 9
     Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:C9"), 2, 0)
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:C9"), 3, 0)
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I run, combo1 is not only 2 selections of toy1 and toy2, but it repeat toy1 4 times and toy2 4 times.

When I select combo 2 and 3, only single value is shown, not the whole list.

Comment: Thanks so much Harun24HR...It worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very interesting that I was working on a project which had similar requirements. I couldn't finish it up full project. Here is code to meet your requirement. Here when you will select any value to `cboToyType` and will go to `cboWheel` it will take little time to run the code. You can optimize codes to faster it.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("Z:Z").ClearContents
    ws.Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("Z1"), Unique:=True
    ws.Range("Z1").ClearContents

    Me.cboToyType.RowSource = ws.Range("Z2").CurrentRegion.Address
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub cboToyType_AfterUpdate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("AB:AD").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.cboToyType
    ws.Range("B:B").Copy ws.Range("AB1")
    ws.Range("AB:AB").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    ws.Range("C:C").Copy ws.Range("AD1")
    ws.Range("AD:AD").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    ws.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
    ws.Range("AB1").ClearContents
    ws.Range("AD1").ClearContents

    Me.cboWheel.RowSource = ws.Range("AB2").CurrentRegion.Address
    Me.cboName.RowSource = ws.Range("AD2").CurrentRegion.Address
    Set ws = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Sample File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FDuXGf998n5LNAQnX_NDZDpfEI8IPR5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Glad to know! If you found it working, then accept the answer so that other user can see the question is solved.

Comment: Thanks again..and I still have another requirement that if I have two toytypes like toy1 and toy11. When I filter from toy1 both the data from toy1 and toy11 get filtered and comes accordingly. What should we change?